# How get Image bitmap in onActivityResult and Delete image after image set in imageview

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I am trying to open camera in Marshmallow and nougat using FileProvider but not getting the bitmap to show captured image in imageview in onActivityResult method.Even i tried to get bitmap from image path. Here is my code

```
image_click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });



    }

    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.xyz.dummyapp.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try{
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoURI.getPath());
                mImageView.setImageURI(photoURI);
            File file=new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            if (file.exists()){
                if (file.delete()){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            }
           catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

        }
    } 



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.xyz.dummyapp/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Comment: You are not saving `photoURI`, or anything to build it, in the saved instance state `Bundle`. Your process can be terminated at any point while the camera app is in the foreground, and in that case, your field will be `null`. [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) demonstrating the proper use of `FileProvider` with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your code doesn't contain everything. But here are some points to note:

- You should save photos in the device public directory

> Generally, any photos that the user captures with the device camera should be saved on the device in the public external storage so they are accessible by all apps.

(Taken from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html))

- If you do so - you need to declare the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

- With Android Marshmallow you have then request the permission for that. Here is a simplified version of that:

.

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 99);
...
....
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, @NonNull final String[] permissions, @NonNull final int[] grantResults) {
      // Execute your code to create the file and start the camera intent here
}
```

(Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html))

- You have also to use the `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` from `Environment` as `storageDir`

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);`

- Your `file_path.xml` should now point to `Pictures/`:

`<external-path name="my_pictures" path="Pictures/"/>`

- In your `onActivityResult` you can simply use the `photoUri` field which you received from `FileProvider#getUriForFile` to set to the image:

`imageView.setImageURI(photoUri);`

For me the changes helps to make a working example:
[image: Take photos with camera and receive image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use this library for camera and gallery : https://github.com/jrvansuita/PickImage  you don't needs to convert image in to bitmap.and this library is working fine in Marshmallow and nougat.